# Want to implement "to_datetime" function for my case

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I want to register my dt0 column which is in the format of "1/1/2020  12:00:00 PM" and is incremented for every 0.1 sec with "to_datetime" in python.

I tried the following but it gives an error "Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00".

`df.dt0=pd.to_datetime(df.dt0)`

Is it because my intervals are too small? Can someone recommend a better/working solution.

Here are the columns that I want to convert from my table

| No. | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/15/2020 | 12:00:00 PM |
| 2 | 1/15/2020 | 12:00:00 PM |
| 3 | 1/15/2020 | 12:00:00 PM |
| 4 | 1/15/2020 | 12:00:00 PM |
| 5 | 1/15/2020 | 12:00:00 PM |
| 6 | 1/15/2020 | 12:00:00 PM |
| 7 | 1/15/2020 | 12:00:00 PM |
| 8 | 1/15/2020 | 12:00:00 PM |
| 9 | 1/15/2020 | 12:00:00 PM |
| 10 | 1/15/2020 | 12:00:00 PM |
| 11 | 1/15/2020 | 12:00:00 PM |
| 12 | 1/15/2020 | 12:00:00 PM |

Comment: Add some rows of  the data frame to the question.

Comment: Where is `incremented for every 0.1 sec` in the `Time` column?

Answer (score 0):

First convert joined both columns to datetimes:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'], 
                                format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
print (df)
    No.       Date         Time            datetime
0     1  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
1     2  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
2     3  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
3     4  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
4     5  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
5     6  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
6     7  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
7     8  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
8     9  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
9    10  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
10   11  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
11   12  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
```

And then add counter of duplicated `datetime` with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) multiple by `100` and converted to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['datetime'] += pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby('datetime').cumcount().mul(100), unit='ms')
print (df)
    No.       Date         Time                datetime
0     1  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00.000
1     2  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00.100
2     3  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00.200
3     4  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00.300
4     5  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00.400
5     6  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00.500
6     7  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00.600
7     8  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00.700
8     9  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00.800
9    10  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00.900
10   11  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:01.000
11   12  1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:01.100
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your target use the following line

```
df['dt0'] = df.apply(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x.Date+' '+x.Time),axis=1)
```

***Verification:***

df

```
          Date         Time                 dt0
No.                                            
1    1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
2    1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
3    1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
4    1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
5    1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
6    1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
7    1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
8    1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
9    1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
10   1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
11   1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
12   1/15/2020  12:00:00 PM 2020-01-15 12:00:00
```

df.info()

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 12 entries, 1 to 12
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   Date    12 non-null     object        
 1   Time    12 non-null     object        
 2   dt0     12 non-null     datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(2)
memory usage: 384.0+ bytes
```

as seen `dt0` is `datetime64[ns]`